# B language limits (table sizes)

Tags: compiler-construction, limit, b-lang

The official B tutorial says that the compiler gives two letters if an error occurs. The letter combinations include:

- `>c` - case table overflow
- `>e` - expression table overflow
- `>i` - label table overflow
- `>s` - symbol table overflow

Instead of using malloc in my B compiler, I would like to statically allocate the tables.

What are minimum sizes of the case, label and symbol tables?

Comment: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/btut.html

Comment: Ah.  Well, its *your* compiler. Set them to whatever lets you compile typical B programs that you encounter.  As a practical matter, you aren't going to encounter any B programs in the wild, so set them for the toy program you are compiling; if it won't compile because you set them large enough, make them bigger.  Why is this a difficult decision?

Comment: Your question would have been less confusing with some context.  Most of us old-timers aren't expecting a question about a 1960s language, and most of the newbies have never heard of it.